# "A communication scheme" - what is the scope?

Tags: discussion

In the site's help centre, the list of suitable topics includes "A communications scheme".

What exactly does it cover? My mother-in-law and I have a "communications scheme".

My point is, where is the boundary between electronics and computer science with respect to the requirement?

It's surprisingly vague for a site within a group that is particularly intolerant to off-topic questions.

Comment: You can always ask, and if we think it's off topic we can migrate it to Stack Overflow / Computational Science / Programmers / whatever. It's entirely possible there are questions that can be on topic on two or more SE sites.

Answer (score 2):

"Communication scheme" in this context is limited to a *electronic* communication scheme, obviously.

Examples would be discussion of your own RS-485 protocol, details of CAN, or Ethernet, or how a UART works at the bit level, etc, etc, etc.